# Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Test run failed to complete. Expected 1 tests, received 0'. Check device logcat for details

Tags: java, android, android-instrumentation

The code is compiled, then starts running the tests from the project and then falls.

I use here gradle, junit, espresso

```
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    public ExampleInstrumentedTest() {

    }

    @ClassRule
    public static DeviceAnimationTestRule
            deviceAnimationTestRule = new DeviceAnimationTestRule();
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<My_Activity> mLoginActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<My_Activity>(My_Activity.class);
    @Rule
    public UiThreadTestRule uiThreadTestRule = new UiThreadTestRule();

 @Test
    public void CreateAndSaveTaskEntity() throws Throwable {

        uiThreadTestRule.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                com.falah.eats.view.base.screen.SplashScreen activity = mLoginActivityTestRule.getActivity();
                activity.getWindow()
                        .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: so, have you checked the logs?

Comment: Please check device is connected or not. May be USB device is not connected.

Comment: @Stultuske Ok I will check sure.

Comment: @Bebin T.N  No my device was already connected.